# Width of contentView in UITableViewCell is different for each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, pure-layout

In an `UITableViewController` defined in a Storyboard with Auto Layout enabled, a `UITableViewCell` subclass is created programatically (no IB prototype cell) and sets constraints through `updateConstraints` using [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout).

For some reason, the table view has each contentView with a different width, instead of using the const width of `UITableView`.

[image]

Here's the `init` and `updateConstraints` method of `UITableViewCell` subclass -

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        _nameLabel = [GTPaddedLabel newAutoLayoutView];
        _nameLabel.font = [BQFontUtil standardFontSize:StandardFontSize1a bold:YES italic:NO];
        _nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        _drugType = [UILabel newAutoLayoutView];
        _drugType.font = [BQFontUtil standardFontSize:StandardFontSize0 bold:NO italic:NO];
        _drugType.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        _drugType.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        _genericsLabel = [UILabel newAutoLayoutView];
        _genericsLabel.font = [BQFontUtil standardFontSize:StandardFontSize0 bold:NO italic:NO];
        _genericsLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        _regimen = [UILabel newAutoLayoutView];
        _regimen.font = [BQFontUtil standardFontSize:StandardFontSize0 bold:NO italic:NO];
        _regimen.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_drugType];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_genericsLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_regimen];

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    if (!constraintsCreated) {
//        [self.contentView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        [UIView autoSetPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forConstraints:^{
            [_nameLabel autoSetContentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis:ALAxisVertical];
        }];

        [_nameLabel autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 0, 8) excludingEdge:ALEdgeBottom];

        [_genericsLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeading withInset:16];
        [_genericsLabel autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:_nameLabel withOffset:4];
        [_genericsLabel autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:21];

        [_drugType autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing withInset:16];
        [_drugType autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:_nameLabel withOffset:4];
        [_drugType autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeading toEdge:ALEdgeTrailing ofView:_genericsLabel withOffset:8];
        [_drugType autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:21];

        [_regimen autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:_genericsLabel withOffset:2];
        [_regimen autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:21];

        [_regimen autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing withInset:16];
        [_regimen autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeading withInset:16];
        [_regimen autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:8];

        constraintsCreated = YES;
    }
    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

**Why does contentView (brown color) doesn't have the same width as the table view?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's a workaround, it works well when I'm constraining contentView's width to cell's width -

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    if (!constraintsCreated) {
        [self.contentView autoSetDimension:ALDimensionWidth toSize:self.frame.size.width];
        ...
    }  
}
```